# Remove comment anchor # and everything to ?search but leave ? and the rest

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

Hi I wrote a javascript that checks the...

```
document.location.search.substring(1,document.location.search.length)
```

But I noticed if there is a comment anchor in it, it looks like this...

```
www.sample.com/sample.html#commentxxx?somethinghereIneed
```

How do I to remove the # and everything up to the question mark (leave that)

So I would have this now...

```
www.sample.com/sample.html?somethinghereIneed
```

A regex can go where the "????" is below correct?
And **Important**...
If it does not find #anchor it will do nothing? Leave it alone, Correct?

```
var removeAnchortoMark = document.location.replace('????', '');
```

And to strip off the # and everything after it... what would that be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
var removeAnchortoMark = document.location.replace('#[^?]*', '');
```

Comment: There we go... exactly what I need I'm going to test it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
//gets the url variables and return them as an associative array.
function getUrlVars(){
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++){
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}
```

This will get everything after the ?. So say your url is www.stackoverflow.com?this=that&mine=yours.

Then this will return an array like this.

```
vars['this'] = 'that';
vars['mine'] = 'yours';
```

Comment: This will probably work but I thought something like this can be done with an easy regex? I'm shooting for the smallest amount of code.

Comment: Oh... that's getting all the variables. I can use that also. In the question I just needed to get rid of the #comment in the url... you see what I mean?

Comment: yea just try this line then. window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');

Comment: hmmm... ok. that might actually work better for what I need. I going to test both now. Thanks